# Closing a frame from an applet

Tags: java, applet, awt, frame

I'm trying to make a console for a java game, in an applet. The console is an independant Frame with a TextArea, used to show loading/downloading progression.
I'm running into some problems when I try to hide the console on closing.

Here is the simplified code :

```
//Method inherited from the Applet class
public void init() {
    console = new Frame();
    console.setSize(500, 300);
    console.addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter(){
        public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e) {
            console.setVisible(false);
        }
    });

    consoleText = new TextArea();
    consoleText.setSize(500, 300);

    console.add(consoleText);

    console.setVisible(true);

    gameThread = new Thread() {
        public void run() {
            mainLoop();
        }
    };
    gameThread.start();
}
```

The thread "gameThread" simply hang when I close the Frame "console". Even when I replace "console.setVisible(false);" with "console.setExtendedState(Frame.ICONIFIED);", the thread still hang without any warning.
While running the applet in a browser, I have to kill the process in the task manager. Very annoying.

Using a JFrame instead does the exact same thing, except the bug is harder to reproduce.

I just want the user to be able to get rid of the console.

Does anybody have an idea ? Thanks !

Comment: My advice is - dump the applet completely and launch the frame (`JFrame`) based game using [Java Web Start](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/java-web-start/info).  The problem will be solved, and JWS offers many advantages over a frame launched from an applet ( including, but not limited to, the fact that the user can close the browser and still use the game ;).

Comment: I only use the Frame as a console to display loading stuff. The game run in a Canvas on the applet itself. Java web start is great, but I think an applet offers more transparency than a java web start app : to the user, it's like a flash game.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that you shouldn't be using a Frame/JFrame for this but rather a JDialog, since the window is behaving as a dialog. Also be sure that you're using a JApplet rather than an Applet.

**Edit**
Note that I cannot reproduce your problem based on your displayed code snippet. Consider creating and posting an [SSCCE](http://SSCCE.org) that would show us the problem directly.

**Edit 2**
My SSCCE that does not reproduce your problem:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class AppletEg extends JApplet {
   private static final int MAX_LOOP = 30;
   private static final long SLEEP_TIME = 500;
   private JFrame console;
   private JTextArea consoleText;
   private Thread gameThread;

   @Override
   public void init() {
      console = new JFrame();
      console.setSize(500, 300);
      console.addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter() {
         public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e) {
            console.setVisible(false);
         }
      });

      consoleText = new JTextArea();
      consoleText.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(500, 300));

      console.add(new JScrollPane(consoleText));

      console.setVisible(true);

      gameThread = new Thread() {
         public void run() {
            mainLoop();
         }
      };
      gameThread.start();
   }

   private void mainLoop() {
      for (int i = 0; i < MAX_LOOP; i++) {
         System.out.println("I: " + i);
         try {
            Thread.sleep(SLEEP_TIME);
         } catch (InterruptedException e) {
         }
      }
   }
}
```

**Edit 3**
My SSCCE using a JDialog:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class AppletEg extends JApplet {
   private static final int MAX_LOOP = 30;
   private static final long SLEEP_TIME = 500;
   private JDialog console;
   private JTextArea consoleText;
   private Thread gameThread;

   @Override
   public void init() {
      Window win = SwingUtilities.getWindowAncestor(this);
      console = new JDialog(win);
      consoleText = new JTextArea();
      consoleText.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(500, 300));

      console.add(new JScrollPane(consoleText));
      console.pack();
      console.setLocationByPlatform(true);
      console.setVisible(true);

      gameThread = new Thread() {
         public void run() {
            mainLoop();
         }
      };
      gameThread.start();
   }

   private void mainLoop() {
      for (int i = 0; i < MAX_LOOP; i++) {
         System.out.println("i: " + i);
         try {
            Thread.sleep(SLEEP_TIME);
         } catch (InterruptedException e) {
         }
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: I'm sorry, but I was totally unable to recreate the bug myself. I provided the code to show how the threads/events are done. There is a LOT of line to rewrite. In the thread I'm loading a lot of images to OpenGL textures : the bug could come from anywhere. I still don't see why it's happening. How the frame can communicate to the thread is beyond me. Thanks to you, I at least know it's not because of AWT : the bug clearly come from the mainLoop() method. It only happen during loading : while the game is running, I can close the frame without hang. I found a more elegant way to do it anyway.